# Adding a Struct to a queue

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, queue

I'm currenty coding a circular queue. Right now my code only accepts ints to add to the queue. My objetive is to be able to add the information of 10 different jewelry pieces to the queue.

As I said, my objective is to code a jeweler work organizer. User inputs client name, type of piece, weight, type of metal and metal law. Then all of that information is stored in one "slot" of my queue. That way the jeweler knows the specific order to work (First in, first out)

So this is my question: how do I add information of a jewelry piece to one "slot" of my queue.

my code adds ints to queue, I want to add the info of a jewelry peice struct. how can I acheive this?

This is what i have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// macros:
 // INT MIN specifies the minimum value that can be used beyond that limit
#define QUEUE_EMPTY INT_MIN

// creating queue struct 
typedef struct{
 int *values;
 int head, tail, inputNumber, size;
} queue;

// declaring functions 
void iniQueue(queue *q, int sizeMax);
bool queueEmpty(queue *q);
bool queueFull(queue *q);
void deleteQueue(queue *q);
bool enqueue(queue *q, int values);
int dequeue(queue *q);




// creating jewel struct
typedef struct{
 char client[50];
 char partType[25];
 double weight;
 char metal[10];
 int law;
}part;

// queue init
void iniQueue(queue *q, int sizeMax){
 q->size = sizeMax;
 // Allocating memory to the array
 q->values = malloc(sizeof(int) * q->size);
 q->inputNumber = 0; // creating empty array
 q->head = 0;
 q->tail = 0;
}

// Func to check if queue is empty
  // returns true if inputs == 0
bool queueEmpty(queue *q){
 return(q->inputNumber == 0);
}

// Func to check is queue is full
  // returns true if inputs == size
bool queueFull(queue *q){
 return (q->inputNumber == q->size);
}

// Destroy queue (free queue)
  // this to avoid memory leaks (short lived data structures)
void deleteQueue(queue *q){
 free(q->values);
}

// ++ Enqueue ++
bool enqueue(queue *q, int values){
 // Check if the queue is full:
 if (queueFull(q)){
  return false; // the queue is already full
 }
  
 // if there is still space, add values
 q->values[q->tail] = values;
 // move indicates from the queue (the module is used to get the rest in case queue> = size)
   // the module replaces: if (queue> = size, then queue = 0)
 q->tail = (q-> tail + 1) % q->size;
// increase the input counter by one
 q->inputNumber++;
 return true;
}

// ++ Dequeue ++
int dequeue(queue *q){
 int result;

 // Checking if the queue is empty
 if(queueEmpty(q)){
  return QUEUE_EMPTY;
 }

 result = q->values[q->head];
 q->head = (q-> head + 1) % q->size;
 q->inputNumber--;

 return result;
}

// ++ Display ++ 
void display(queue *q){
 // check if it is empty
 if (QUEUE_EMPTY == true){
  printf("Your work-list is empty\n");
 }
 printf("The number of elements in the list are %d", inputNumber);
 printf("The elements of the Queue are: \n");
 //note: didn't displayed elements yet.
}


int main(){
 // Local variables
 int choice, add, t;

 // creating the queue
 queue q1;
 iniQueue(&q1, 10);

 // creating pieces of jewelery (to be filled by user)
 part p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10;

while(420){
 // Menu
 printf ("Welcome to your jewelry organizer! \n");
 printf ("1 - Add Job \n");
 printf ("2 - Complete Current Job \n");
 printf ("3 - View full job list \n");
 printf ("4 - Add Job \n");
 printf ("Enter the number to perform the desired action:");
 scanf("%d", &choice);

 // Actions
 switch (choice){
 case 1:
  printf("Enter a number to add to the Queue:");
  scanf("%d", &add);
  enqueue(&q1, add);
  break;
 
 case 2: 
  dequeue(&q1);
  break;

 case 3:
  display(&q1);
  // show list
  break;
 
 case 4: 
  exit(0);

 default:
  printf("Invalid choice ...");
    }
  }
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please note you haven’t asked a question. Edit the question and include information about the problem

Comment: I explicitly added the question to my post. i hope my question is more clear now

Comment: In the `queue` struct` change `int *valores;` to be `pieza*valores;` and then store a pointer to each instance of the jewellery struct. That's not quite right as I can't read the non-english variables and comments. But generally you need to make the queue store the right type of data.

Comment: OT: It's a real, real bad idea to use words from your native language for variables and/or functions. Use meaningful English words so that your code is easy to read for programmers all over the world.

Comment: OT: The same apply to comments... use English

Comment: It's pretty easy to do what you ask for. In C structs can be assigned, passed, etc. just the same way as integers. So just change all ints refering to stored values to structs.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I will start to code in english!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// macros:
 // INT MIN especifica el minimo valor que se puede utilizar mas alla de ese limite 
#define QUEUE_EMPTY INT_MIN


// creating jewel struct
struct part{
  char client[50];
  char partType[25];
  double weight;
  char metal[10];
  int law;
};



// creating queue struct 
struct queue{
  int *values;
  int head, tail, inputNumber, size;
  struct part *p;
};
// declaring functions 


void iniQueue(struct queue *q, int sizeMax);
bool queueEmpty(struct queue *q);
bool queueFull(struct queue *q);
void deleteQueue(struct queue *q);
bool enqueue(struct queue *q, int values, struct part *p1);
struct part* dequeue(struct queue *q);


// queue init
void iniQueue(struct queue *q, int sizeMax){
 q->size = sizeMax;
 // acolcando el array
 q->values = malloc(sizeof(int) * q->size);
 q->inputNumber = 0; // creando arreglo vacío 
 q->head = 0;
 q->tail = 0;
 q->p = (struct part *)malloc(sizeof(struct part) * q->size);
}

// Func to check if queue is empty
  // regresa true si entradas == 0
bool queueEmpty(struct queue *q){
 return(q->inputNumber == 0);
}

// Func to check is queue is full 
  // regresa true si entradas ==  size 
bool queueFull(struct queue *q){
 return (q->inputNumber == q->size);
}

// Destroy queue (free queue)
  // esto para evitar memory leaks (short lived data structures)
void deleteQueue(struct queue *q){
 free(q->values);
 free(q->p);
}

// ++ Enqueue ++
bool enqueue(struct queue *q, int values, struct part *p1){
 // Checar si es queue esta lleno:
 if (queueFull(q)){
  return false; // el queue ya esta lleno
 }
 //si aun hay espacio, agregar values
 q->values[q->tail] = values;
 q->p[q->tail] = *p1;
 // mover indica de la tail (se usa el modulo para obtener el resto en caso de que tail >= size)
   // el modulo remplaza: if (tail >= size, entonces tail = 0)
 q->tail = (q-> tail + 1) % q->size;
 // aumentar por uno el contador de entradas
 q->inputNumber++;
 return true;
}

// ++ Dequeue ++
struct part* dequeue(struct queue *q){
 int resultado;
  struct part *result;

 // Checando si el queue está vacío
 if(queueEmpty(q)){
    printf("queue is empty.");
  return result;
 }

// resultado = q->values[q->head];
// q->head = (q-> head + 1) % q->size;
// q->inputNumber--;


result = &q->p[q->head];
  q->head = (q-> head + 1) % q->size;
  q->inputNumber--;
  
// return resultado;
  return result;
}

// ++ Display ++
void display (struct queue * q) {
  // check if it is empty
  if (QUEUE_EMPTY == true) {
    printf ("Your work-list is empty \n");
    return;
  }
  printf ("The number of elements in the list are %d", q->inputNumber);
  printf ("\nThe elements of the Queue are: \n");
  for (int i=0; i<q->inputNumber; i++) {
    printf("Details about product number : %d\n",i+1);
    printf("%s %s %lf %s %d\n",q->p[i].client,q->p[i].partType,q->p[i].weight,q->p[i].metal,q->p[i].law);
  }
}


int main(){
 // Variables locales
 int choice, add, t;

 //creando el queue 
 struct queue q1;
 iniQueue(&q1, 10);

 // creating peices of jewelery (to be filled by user)
 struct part *p1,*p2,*p3,*p4,*p5,*p6,*p7,*p8,*p9,*p10;

  while (420) {
    // Menu
    printf ("\nWelcome to your jewelry organizer! \n");
    printf ("1 - Add Job \n");
    printf ("2 - Complete Current Job \n");
    printf ("3 - View full job list \n");
    printf ("4 - Exit \n");
    printf ("Enter the number to perform the desired action:");
    scanf ("%d", &choice);
    struct part part1;
    
  // Actions
  switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      printf("Enter Client name : ");
      scanf(" %s", part1.client);
      printf("Enter Part Type : ");
      scanf(" %s", part1.partType);
      printf("Enter Metal : ");
      scanf(" %s", part1.metal);
      printf("Enter Weight : ");
      scanf(" %lf", &part1.weight);
      printf("Enter law : ");
      scanf(" %d", &part1.law);
      enqueue(&q1, add,&part1);
      break;
    
    case 2:
      part1 = *dequeue(&q1);
      printf("%s %s %s %lf %d",part1.client,part1.partType,part1.metal,part1.weight,part1.law);
      break;
    
    case 3:
      display(&q1);
      // show list
      break;
    
    case 4:
      exit(0);
      
    default:
      printf ("Invalid choice ...");
  }
}
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the english, I first translated your code in english then edited it.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. This dose exactly what I wanted. Sorry for the spanish code...I'll start to code in english from now on. Happy coding :)

Comment: No problem! I edited your question and translated your whole code in english, but as I didn't have enough reputation, my edits are only accepted if someone reviews my code. so I guess no one reviewed my edit till now !